# ranlib error while cross-compiling ffmpeg x264 for android on osx 10.8

Tags: ffmpeg, osx-mountain-lion, cross-compiling, android-ndk-r5

I wanted to compile a ffmpg x264 lib for android https://github.com/edisonw/android-ffmpeg-x264. I am using Mountain Lion (Mac OSX 10.8.4). I already installed libtool and yasm via brew but still get the following error:

```
ffmpeg/libavdevice/libavdevice.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/Users/Test/github/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/obj/local/armeabi/libencoding.so] Error 1
```

After that it stuck and I have no Idea why, according to the owner it was possible to build on a Lion (Mac OSX 10.7.x).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What configure line did you use?

Comment: @MultimediaMike What do you mean with configure line?

Comment: Before you ran 'make', which eventually produced this error, you ran './configure'. What were the parameters you passed to './configure' (if any)?

Comment: @MultimediaMike ok I see, used for ffmpeg https://raw.github.com/edisonw/android-ffmpeg-x264/master/Project/jni/configure_ffmpeg.sh and for x264 https://raw.github.com/edisonw/android-ffmpeg-x264/master/Project/jni/configure_x264.sh